# Emulating blocking Console keyboard input in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, console, emulation

I need to write a console emulator in C#. I want to replace `System.Console` with something that can work in full-screen. My approach is to make a maximized Form with no borders.

One challenge I am facing is how to convert the event-driven, non-blocking keyboard input into a blocking one, or more specifically, how would you go about implementing an equivalent of `Console.ReadKey()` in a Windows Form.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you really want to have fully blocking console window. What you need is more like PowerShell or standard console window. I mean that it is doubtful that you will be against having the ability to move the window, copy data from the console and so on.

---

So, the console described further is based upon `TextBox`. Why not on the `Form` itself? - Because multiline, readonly TextBox already provide a lot of facilities that will simplify our `Console` (`AppendText`, text selection, copying ...).

## 1. Idea and interfaces:

As you have already mentioned in the question, WinForms have completely different model from console application with message queue and event based processing. So, to get data from event and prevent form from becoming irresponsive we cannot block this event loop. To achieve such behaviour we will run our console-based code on different thread with `Task.Run` and unblock input-dependent "console" calls from events in main form thread. The cornerstones of the application will be the next two interfaces:

```
public interface IConsole
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo ReadKey();

    void WriteLine(String line);
}

public interface IConsoleContext
{
    void Run(Action<IConsole> main);
}
```

First is the Console itself with methods that reflect standard console capabilities. Second will run our console related code(represented by action) on some another thread, providing some console object to this action.

Our `IConsoleContext` implementation will be `TextBoxConsoleContext` with its private nested class `TextBoxConsole` as `IConsole`

## 2. Main form code

Here is the code we will use in our form to demonstrate the console. Assuming that we have textBox `textBox_Console`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var consoleContext = new TextBoxConsoleContext(this.textBox_Console);

    consoleContext.Run((console) =>
    {
        console.WriteLine("Welcome to the TextBox console");
        console.WriteLine("Press any key:");
        console.ReadKey();

        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = new ConsoleKeyInfo();


        console.WriteLine("Press y to continue: ");
        do
        {
            keyInfo = console.ReadKey();

            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == 'y')
                break;

            console.WriteLine("You have entered another key, please enter y to continue:");
        }
        while (true);

        console.WriteLine("Thank you for your cooperation.");
    });
}
```

## 3. The `TextBoxConsoleContext` itself:

```
public class TextBoxConsoleContext : IConsoleContext
{
    #region Nested types

    private class TextBoxConsole : IConsole
    {
        #region Fields

        private TextBoxConsoleContext parent;

        #endregion


        #region Constructors

        public TextBoxConsole(TextBoxConsoleContext parent)
        {
            if (parent == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");

            this.parent = parent;
        }

        #endregion


        #region IConsole implementation

        public ConsoleKeyInfo ReadKey()
        {
            var key = this.parent.m_Queue.Dequeue();
            this.WriteLine(key.KeyChar.ToString());
            return key;
        }

        public void WriteLine(string line)
        {
            Action writeLine = () =>
                {
                    var textToAppend = String.Format("{0}{1}",
                        line,
                        Environment.NewLine);

                    this.parent.m_TextBox.AppendText(textToAppend);
                };

            this.parent.m_TextBox.Invoke(writeLine);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion


    #region Fields

    private TextBox m_TextBox;
    private OnRequestProducerConsumerQueue<ConsoleKeyInfo> m_Queue = new OnRequestProducerConsumerQueue<ConsoleKeyInfo>();

    private Boolean m_Shift;
    private Boolean m_Alt;
    private Boolean m_Ctrl;
    private ConsoleKey m_KeyInfo;

    #endregion


    #region Constructors

    public TextBoxConsoleContext(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");


        this.m_TextBox = textBox;
        this.m_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
        // Event handler that will read key down data before key press
        this.m_TextBox.KeyDown += (obj, e) =>
            {
                this.m_Shift = e.Modifiers.HasFlag(Keys.Shift);
                this.m_Alt = e.Modifiers.HasFlag(Keys.Alt);
                this.m_Ctrl = e.Modifiers.HasFlag(Keys.Control);

                if (!Enum.TryParse<ConsoleKey>(e.KeyCode.ToString(), out this.m_KeyInfo))
                {
                    this.m_KeyInfo = ConsoleKey.Escape;
                }                   
            };

        this.m_TextBox.KeyPress += (obj, e) =>
            {
                this.m_Queue.EnqueueIfRequired(new ConsoleKeyInfo(e.KeyChar, 
                    this.m_KeyInfo, 
                    this.m_Shift, 
                    this.m_Alt,
                    this.m_Ctrl));
            };
    }

    #endregion


    #region IConsoleContext implementation

    public void Run(Action<IConsole> main)
    {
        if (main == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("main");

        var console = new TextBoxConsole(this);

        Task.Run(() =>
            main(console));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## 4. `OnRequestProducerConsumerQueue`

**EDIT**: I have replaced initial queue class with this much simpler class that uses single lock object with Monitor calls. This code is based on the condition variable pattern.

**REMARK**: I just wanted to replace the previous abuse of sync constructs I have posted initially. This version doesn't change anything in the behaviour, and the `EnqueueIfRequired` in this implementation will be more than useless if you need to implement `ReadLine` methods (but you can add to it some predicate logic that will allow queening till the line terminator appears).

```
public class OnRequestProducerConsumerQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> m_Items = new Queue<T>();
    private object m_lock = new Object();
    private Int32 m_NeedItems = 0;

    public void EnqueueIfRequired(T value)
    {
        lock (this.m_lock)
        {
            if (this.m_NeedItems == 0)
                return;

            this.m_Items.Enqueue(value);
            this.m_NeedItems--;

            Monitor.PulseAll(this.m_lock);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (this.m_lock)
        {
            this.m_NeedItems++;

            while (this.m_Items.Count < 1)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(this.m_lock);
            }

            return this.m_Items.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is pretty much what I had in mind, but couldn't really make it work. I noticed that the solution requires .NET 4.5, so I will install it and test your proposal. I actually would prefer having a Form rather than a TextBox, as I need capabilities to write text at an arbitrary position and in different colors, but this is irrelevant, I can surely convert the solution to use a Form.

Comment: I will surely accept the solution as soon as I evaluate it. I need to actually convert it a bit, and here's why:

Comment: I will surely accept the solution as soon as I evaluate it. I need to actually convert it a bit, and here's why: 
My code goes something like this  
IConsole console = //load a console implementation by name using reflection; 
while (true) {
  char key = console.ReadKey; 
  // do something with the key
}. 
This code is sealed and I cannot change it to read:
consoleContext.Run((console) => {
  console.ReadKey();
  // do sth
}
so I need to make ReadKey() (and all the other methods) self contained. It is not clear to me yet if it's possible, mainly because I haven't used .NET for a while now.

Comment: @dirkgently I understand, no one forces you to accept something that doesn't fully solve the problem. And in future post [more context information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) with some relevant code examples in the question, for it will allow answerers to reply with more appropriate solutions, it will also make the post look less like some "give me the codez" question and more like well-researched and well-written question about the interesting problem.

Comment: @dirkgently I do not know the exact situation you have in the code, but, perhaps, async event handlers coupled with TaskCompletionSource-based Tasks for ReadKey may help you. But if the written code is completely unmodifiable and operates from standard event handlers expecting fully synchronous Console model, then I am not sure that what you want can be achieved. At least with more or less mundane methods. Still, decompilation-modification-recomplilation may be an option.

Comment: Here's what I quickly wrote in Java (Swing):
public char ReadKey(){
  semaphore.acquire();
  return key;
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  key = e.getKeyChar();
  semaphore.release();
}
Works like a charm, as AWT has a separate thread for events. The same solution doesn't work in .NET, and I'm not sure if it's possible to implement it using Windows.Forms.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your assistance, and agree that in hindsight, more context information would have been helpful. Nonetheless, thank you for your help, your post was informative and insightful, even if not exactly what I had in mind.